# CSS show line will filtering

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have used an example of a timeline layout as you can see in the JSFiddle. I have added filter buttons and when I use them the line in the middle gets cut off. Can someone help me with this?

See:

https://jsfiddle.net/tc2axpkf/11/
Click on the button TEST or GROEP and see that the line in the middle gets cut off.

```
.timeline:before {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
content:" ";
width: 2px;
background: #ffffff;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with floatting elements that need to be cleared.

```
 .timeline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 300; 
    overflow:hidden; /* should be enough */
}
```

see for infos : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-4

> If you are in a situation where you always know what the succeeding element is going to be, you can apply the clear: both; value to that element and go about your business. This is ideal as it requires no fancy hacks and no additional elements making it perfectly semantic. Of course things don't typically work out that way and we need to have more float-clearing tools in our toolbox.

In your case, you can use :

> **The Overflow Method**
>
> The Overflow Method relies on setting the overflow CSS property on a parent element. If this property is set to auto or hidden on the parent element, the parent will expand to contain the floats, effectively clearing it for succeeding elements. This method can be beautifully semantic as it may not require an additional elements. However if you find yourself adding a new div just to apply this, it is equally as non-semantic as the empty div method and less adaptable. Also bear in mind that the overflow property isn't specifically for clearing floats. Be careful not to hide content or trigger unwanted scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the `.timeline-inverted` section is removed from the dom.
After this your `.timeline` collapses because of floated elements.

Try to add an clearfix:

```
.timeline:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```